# How do I count the vowels from two words connected with "..."

Tags: c++, string, char

I need to read words from a text. The text sounds something like this:

```
Maria has two apples in her...closet
```

When I read my text, `her...closet` is read like one word. I need to separate the words and count the vowels in each one. If the number of vowels from the word is equal or greater than a given number `k`, then print the word.
For example:

Input:

```
2
Maria has two apples in her...closet
```

Desired output:

```
Maria
apples
closet
```

This is my code for now:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int is_letter(char s) {
     if (('a' <= s && s <= 'z') || ('A' <= s && s <= 'Z')) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

int main(){
ifstream fin("date.in");
const int LIM = 261;
const int LIMV = 11;
char vowals[LIMV] = "aeiouAEIOU";
char s[LIM];
int k;
cin >> k;
while (fin >> s) {
    int found_letter = 1;
    int nrVowels = 0;
    int letter = -1;
    int n = strlen(s);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if(is_letter(s[i])) {
            ++letter;
            found_letter = 1;
            if (strchr(vowals,s[i]))
            ++nrVowels;
        } else {
            found_letter = 0;
            letter = -1;
            }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= letter; ++i) {
        if(nrVowels >= k && found_letter == 1) {
            cout << s[i];
        }
    }
    cout <<"\n";
}

return 0;
}
```

I tried to keep a counter every time I found a desire letter.

Then, if the desired character is a letter, I verify if it is a letter and keep a counter of the vowels found in one word.

If my program finds a character that it is not a letter it resets the counter.
When it's done checking the word, if it has the number of vowels requested and if it is a letter (`found_letter == 1`), then I will print the letter.

My logic problem is that I cannot isolate the words properly.

Comment: Are you not permitted to use the c++ standard library?

Comment: read the sentence into a string, replace any `.` with a space, then split into words, then process individual words. Use `std::string` it will make everything a lot simpler

Comment: `if (('a' <= s && s <= 'z') || ('A' <= s && s <= 'Z')) ` -- No.  It should be `if (std::isalpha(s))`

Answer (score 1):

As always, there are many potential solutions. I will show you an answer, using more modern C++.

To answer you question in the title. You could use a `std::regex` from the [regex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) library. Here you can easily define, what a word is. Other characters that cannot be matched with the regex, are not considered as a part of a word.

Next, if you have string, you can iterate over all regex-matches in the string and with that, extract all words easily. There is a build in iterator for that: The [std::sregex_token_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_token_iterator).

So, now you can simply get all words from a string.

Next, we need to output the words that we can extract to `std::cout`. For this, we can use the function [std::copy_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy). This will copy parts of a range (here all words of the input string), to an output range (here build by the [std::ostream_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator)) , if a condition is matched.

The condition is, that the count of vowels is greater-equal than a user provided threshold.

We will again use a function from the [Algorithms library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm): The [std::count_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) function. We will count the number of vowels and compare it with the given threshold.

With all the above we can create a rather compact program.

Please see:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <regex>
#include <algorithm>

// A regex for a complete word
const std::regex re{ R"(\w+)" };

int main() {
    // Open File and check, if it is open
    if (std::ifstream ifs{ "r:\\data.in" }; ifs) {

        // Get threshold value from user and check for valid value
        if (int threshold{}; (std::cin >> threshold) and (threshold > 0)) {

            // Read the complete file into a string
            std::string text(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs), {});

            // Show result
            std::copy_if(std::sregex_token_iterator(text.begin(), text.end(), re),{},std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"),
                [&](const std::string& s) {return std::count_if(s.begin(), s.end(), [&](const char c) {return (0x208222 >> (c & 0x1f)) & 1; }) >= threshold;});
        }
        else std::cerr << "\nError: Invalid value for threshold\n\n";
    }
    else std::cerr << "\nError: Could not read text file\n\n";
}
```

Please note: This will only work with ASCII characters. If you have a different character set, then you would need to modify the Lambda checking for vowels.

Answer (score 0):

You see, you can actually perform this task with more ease by using the std::string data type (it ignores the whitespace when you `fin` and also doesn't do it letter by letter). So, std::string will allow you to not need to `fin >> s` that many times. You can now also use std::string.substr() function to separate parts of a block of words. What I did can be explained in the code below with comments:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string> // the file for strings
#include <cctype> // the file for isalpha()
using namespace std;

int is_letter(char s) {
    if (isalpha(s)) { // check if letter
       switch (s) { // check if vowel (return 2 if yes)
       case 'a': return 2; break;
       case 'A': return 2; break;
       case 'e': return 2; break;
       case 'E': return 2; break;
       case 'i': return 2; break;
       case 'I': return 2; break;
       case 'o': return 2; break;
       case 'O': return 2; break;
       case 'u': return 2; break;
       case 'U': return 2; break;
       default: return 1; break; // return 1 if letter but not vowel
       }
    }
    return 0; // otherwise return 0 for not letter
}

int main() {
    ifstream fin("date.in");
    string curword = ""; //your inputs of blocks of words will be stored here
    int k; // the vowel limit number
    cin >> k;
    while (fin >> curword) { // input a block of words
        curword = curword + '.'; //in order to make sure the program outputs a valid word even if there are no foreign characters by ending it with a non-alpha character
        int found_letter = 1, nrVowels = 0, letter = 0; // setup counters and values
        for (int i = 0; i < curword.length(); ++i) { // no need to do strlen now
            if(is_letter(curword[i]) != 0) { // see if returns 1 or 2
                ++letter; // if yes, this is a letter
                found_letter = 1; // this acts like a bool just to check whether the current part of the string you are checking has a letter
                if (is_letter(curword[i]) == 2) { // see if vowel
                    ++nrVowels; // if yes, increment vowel counter
                }
            }
            else {
                if ((nrVowels >= k) && (found_letter == 1)) { // if not a letter and letters exist in the current part of the string
                    cout << curword.substr(i - letter, letter) << '\n'; // take substring that omits non alpha characters and output it
                }
                found_letter = 0; // reset as current word has ended
                letter = 0; // reset as current word has ended
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If you input:

```
2 Maria has two apples in her...closet
```

or

```
2
Maria has two apples in her...closet
```

My program runs loops through each block once. For example, when it hits a `.` character in `her...closet`, my program outputs `her`, then runs through and skips the rest of the `.`, then hits `closet` and starts counting again. Finally, it hits the `.` I added at the end of `curword` as a stopper, and outputs it. The stopper is vital in this situation because if `curword` didn't have any foreign characters, it would not output words like `Maria`.

Program output:

```
Maria
apples
closet
```

**Just one last thing: This program only ends when there are no more items to `fin`. Within a proper signal or ending, the program may not `return 0`. I have no definitive proof regarding whether this could be a problem, but just as a warning, here you go.**

Comment: Suggestion: define an `enum`  and return it (instead of 0, 1, 2)